# How to put line break in Concat fuction in VBA

Tags: vba, newline, concatenation

I have very specific issue, I am trying to concat values to string using line break, I tried all possibilities, nothing works. I tried vbnewline, vbLf, CHR(10).

```
Range("M2:M" & AfterDuplastRow).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = _
"=IF(F2=""" & meal & """," & _
"IF(F1<>F2,B2,Concat(M1,CHR(10),B2)),"""")"
```

also I tried like this

```
ActiveCell.Formula = _
"=IF(F2=""" & meal & """," & _
"IF(F1<>F2,B2,Concat(M1," & CHR(10) & ",B2)),"""")"
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: From memory you need a combination of vbCR & vbLF, vbNewLine is the same as vbCR & vbLF.

Answer (score 0):

Use constant `vbNewLine`:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(F2=""" & meal & """,IF(F1<>F2,B2,Concat(M1," & vbNewLine & ",B2)),"""")"
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunatell, it doesn't help. after running code run time error 1004 appears: application-defined or object defined error

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Even if you include a New Line (`vbNewLine`), a Carriage Return (`vbCr`), a Line Feed (`vbLf`), or a Carriage Return *and* a Line Feed (`vbCrLf`), it will **only** be visible in a cell if Wrap Text is turned on for that cell.

As such, try this simple change:

```
Range("M2:M" & AfterDuplastRow).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(F2=""" & meal & """," & _
    "IF(F1<>F2,B2,Concat(M1,CHR(10),B2)),"""")"
Range("M1").WrapText = True 'This line should fix your issue
```

(Also, you may want to read up on [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1))